# Astro, React - children is not a function

Tags: reactjs, astrojs

I have a React component where I return the children as a function and pass data. I am using this in a Astro page.

Foo

```js
type Props = {
  children: (name: string) => JSX.Element;
};

function Foo({ children }: Props) {
  return children("foo");
}
```

Usage

```js
<Foo client:load>
  {(name: string) => <div>Hello from {name}</div>}
</Foo>
```

I get this error when trying so.

```js
Uncaught TypeError: children is not a function
```

When using `<Foo client:only>` the same error occurs.

Using this `Foo` component with *"plain"* React everything works as expected.

Comment: What is name here, is it the element type like 'h1' ? or a key to a reactNode

Comment: @FatehMohamed name is a simple **string** as mentioned in the `Foo` component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Astro's slot functions work server side but React works client side, you can't pass server side functions to client side components, only HTML

Comment: But if I use `client:only="react"` *the component won't render on the server, but will render on the client when the page loads* according to the [Hydrating Interactive Components docs](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/framework-components/#hydrating-interactive-components). So the function will only run on the client right?

Comment: The type of hydration does not matter, server side functions cannot be serialized into client side functions